# GpgmeppConfig.cmake not found

Tags: kde, gnupg, compile, cmake, gpg4win

I am using Craft for building Linux applications in Windows, but the following error occurs when building a Linux application:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package): 
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Gpgmepp" (requested version 1.13.1) with any of the following names: 
**GpgmeppConfig.cmake 
  gpgmepp-config.cmake** 
Add the installation prefix of "Gpgmepp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Gpgmepp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Gpgmepp" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd .. (Get out from the Build folder)
git clone https://github.com/KDE/gpgmepp.git
cd gpgmepp/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
```

Comment: This might be the solution to the issue, but can you at least add one non-code sentence that explains what you are suggesting the original poster do?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The package providing that cmake config in Fedora is called `gpgmepp-devel` and in Debian seems to be called `libgpgmepp-dev`

Fedora install:

```
sudo dnf install gpgmepp-devel
```